# Managing multiple ViewConrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am having a view with next buttons ( for example) "New Game" and "Share with friends" 
and I want if the user clicks on "New game" running "NewGameViewController",and when he clicks "Share" ShareViewController running.
I 've read some docs on developer.apple (TabBar and NavBar) but didn't find a solution

Comment: Are you using Storyboards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NewGameViewController *ngVC = [[NewGameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeNib" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ngVC animated:YES];
```

Same thing in principle for the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You have more chances to do this. The simplest is to use presentModalViewController method of UIVIew. Or you can instantiate a navigation controller and use pushViewController:animated: method of that.

Answer (score -1):

if you not using storyboard or Xib than

```
if you have button New Game and Share than used tag value 0 for new Game and 1 for share with friend.

than follow button action method


-(void)buttonActionMethod:(UIButton *)btn{

if(btn.tag==0)
{
NewganeViewController *newGameController =[[NewGameViewController alloc]int];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:newGameController animation:YES];

}

if(btn.tag==1){
ShareViewContoller *shareViewControler =[[ShareViewController alloc ]init];
[self.navogationController pushViewController:shareViewController animation:YES];
}

}
```